# How to replace empty strings in a 2D array with a character?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, replace

Right so I have this 2D array

```
string[,] board = {
{ "Patrol", "", "", "", "", "" },

{ "", "", "", "Ship", "", "" },

{ "", "", "", "", "", "Carrier" },

{ "", "Destroyer", "", "", "", "Carrier" },

{ "", "Destroyer", "", "", "", "Carrier" },

{ "", "", "", "", "", "" } };
```

And I was wondering what I would have to do to replace all the whitespaces with an "X".

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", board[i, j]));
    }
}
```

I use this to output the array.

Comment: [`string.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: But it's an array?

Comment: *Replace* the whitespace or just *display* it as `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a simple array manipulation

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        if (board[i,j] == "")
            board[i,j] = "X";           
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a saviour, it took me so long to find an answer to this. I'm surprised at how simple it is. Thank you!

Comment: If you're replacing a single character with a single character, you may want to use ' ' and 'X' to avoid unnecessary strings.

Answer (score 1):

To replace spaces by X:

```
for ( int indexD1 = board.GetLowerBound(0); indexD1 <= board.GetUpperBound(0); indexD1++ )
  for ( int indexD2 = board.GetLowerBound(1); indexD2 <= board.GetUpperBound(1); indexD2++ )
    board[indexD1, indexD2] = board[indexD1, indexD2].Replace(" ", "X");
```

But to replace empty strings by "X":

```
for ( int indexD1 = board.GetLowerBound(0); indexD1 <= board.GetUpperBound(0); indexD1++ )
  for ( int indexD2 = board.GetLowerBound(1); indexD2 <= board.GetUpperBound(1); indexD2++ )
    if ( board[indexD1, indexD2] == "" )
      board[indexD1, indexD2] = "X";
```

You can also write this to be scrupulous:

```
if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(board[indexD1, indexD2]) )
```

Comment: I assume your first snippet should have said  `.....Replace(" ", "X");`, edited for you.  Kudos for array bounds checking. :)

Comment: `GetLowerBound` is a little useless, generally, unless having a special array which is rare, but the point of interest if `GetUpperBound` for the dimension. [Make arrays with non-zero lower bounds in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/05/make-arrays-with-non-zero-lower-bounds-in-c/)

Comment: Agreed, about the only time I've used non-zero bounds was in _OLE COM collections_